# How would you make this sentence active?

Tags: active-voice

A grammar checker is saying this sentence is passive:

> When building a house, for example, you use a symbol for a door instead of drawing a detailed picture of the exact door you want, knowing details like that will be figured out later (probably after quite a few arguments).

I'm trying to keep a very casual tone for a very technical topic. "be figured" reads fine to me. I'm unable to come up with something I like better. I'm stumped. Anyone suggestions?

thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to turn off the bad program and trust yourself.

Comment: *A grammar checker is saying this sentence is passive:* It is, but that is not necessarily a bad thing. "knowing details like that will be figured out later" is confusing as "that" appears to related to "you use a symbol for a door" (This is a 'detail'.) If you mean "knowing which door you want", then you should say that.

Comment: (1) That sentence is not passive. (2) One of the clauses is passive; the other clauses aren't. (3) Grammar checkers are crap. Don't pay any attention to them, and distrust anyone who tells you different.

Comment: Commentators agree. Grammar checkers are an aid not a prescription. Your sentence is clear, unambiguous and correct.

Comment: .... knowing you will figure out such details later ...?

Comment: tchrist, I don't trust myself. And it does find some problems, even in text I've had professionally edited. Commas are the worst. I use commas where I want people to pause, which I think is correct, but doesn't match rule based approaches.

Comment: If you don't trust yourself to write English, you probly don't trust yourself to speak it, either. My guess is you're a native speaker, worrying about zombie grammar rules. Don't do it. If you're not a native speaker, that's one thing; but if you are, stop being bamboozled by grammar nazis. Write the way you talk, and as long as you have something worthwhile to say, you're doing fine. Everything else is BS designed to make you feel bad.